# Ethernet MTU problem with Intel Elkhart Lake Platform

Tags: networking, ethernet, intel

I am using [this board](https://www.congatec.com/de/produkte/pico-itx/conga-pa7/) from congatec, and i am using Ubuntu 22.04.

I am trying to set the Ethernet MTU to 9000. Using this command i can see the max Ethernet MTU is 9000:

```
ip -d link list
```

I tried setting it to 9000, but i get this error:

```
xa70@xa70:~$ sudo ifconfig eno2 mtu 9000
SIOCSIFMTU: Invalid argument
```

I can set the mtu to a maximum of 4096:

```
xa70@xa70:~$ sudo ifconfig eno2 mtu 4097
SIOCSIFMTU: Invalid argument
xa70@xa70:~$ sudo ifconfig eno2 mtu 4096
```

I have also tried:

1. Disabling the Ethernet interface before configuring the MTU
2. Enabling Jumbo Packet Support in the Registers of the Ethernet Controller

Does anyone have an idea what i am doing wrong here?

EDIT:

This is the output of the command by jtessier72:

```
*-network:0               
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: Intel Corporation
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 1d.1
   bus info: pci@0000:00:1d.1
   logical name: eno1
   version: 11
   serial: a6:3c:0b:94:06:5e
   size: 10Mbit/s
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt-fd 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=st_gmac driverversion=6.2.0-34-generic duplex=half latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=10Mbit/s
   resources: iomemory:600-5ff irq:125 memory:6001340000-600137ffff


*-network:1
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: Intel Corporation
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 1d.2
   bus info: pci@0000:00:1d.2
   logical name: eno2
   version: 11
   serial: de:db:d7:7b:11:80
   size: 10Mbit/s
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt-fd 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=st_gmac driverversion=6.2.0-34-generic duplex=half latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=10Mbit/s
   resources: iomemory:600-5ff irq:157 memory:6001300000-600133ffff
```

Comment: what does this output show: `sudo lshw -c network`

Comment: See the main post for the output of the command

Comment: That's interesting. Is your port running at 10Mbit/s ?

Comment: Yes, by default it is 10Mbit/s (and it was 10Mbit/s when i typed the command)

Comment: I wonder if there's something limiting the jumbo frames to 4k when 10Mbit/sec

Comment: I changed the speed to 100Mbit/s and tried again, it still did not work

Comment: https://www.spinics.net/lists/netdev/msg893932.html - have a look at this thread (suggest reading all the responses to it). Suggests that maxmtu might be reported by some NICs as what could be supported under optimal conditions. Looks like a limitation in Elkhart Lake NIC supporting only 4096 at least by default.

Comment: I read the thread, and i agree this might be a limitation of the Linux Drivers (it works fine under Windows, so it has to be Linux Drivers). If this was a limitation of the Linux drivers, is there any way to contact Canonical about this bug (since the drivers were developed by Canonical directly)?

Comment: I think this is Linux kernel source, which Canonical would pull in changes from.

Answer (score 0):

According to this [note](http://www.microhowto.info/howto/change_the_mtu_of_a_network_interface.html) the `SIOCSIFMTU: Invalid argument` error message

> indicates that the requested MTU was rejected by the kernel. Typically this would be due to it exceeding the maximum value supported by the interface hardware. In that case you must either reduce the MTU to a value that is supported or obtain more capable hardware.

According to [this thread,](https://www.spinics.net/lists/netdev/msg893932.html) the Elkhart Lake platform may only support 4096 bytes, at least as of 31 Mar 2023.

> The stmmac_change_mtu
> function restricts the MTU to the size of a single queue in the TX
> FIFO.
>
> For instance, on st_gmac without device tree this is by default 4096.

The same thread mentions at least some platforms do not update maxmtu dynamically and only report maxmtu for the best case scenario.
It is possible that your HW may only support up to 4096 (at least given default values).

You should be able to confirm MTU support using:

`sudo ip -d link list {ifname}`

```
~$ sudo ip -d link list ens160
2: ens160: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:50:56:93:c7:ba brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff promiscuity 0 minmtu 60 maxmtu 9000 addrgenmode eui64 numtxqueues 4 numrxqueues 4 gso_max_size 65536 gso_max_segs 65535 parentbus pci parentdev 0000:03:00.0
    altname enp3s0
```

Note the `minmtu 60` and `maxmtu 9000` parts of the output above.

Comment: I am sure the hardware supports 9000, and this command also confirms it as this command for both Ethernet controller shows maxmtu 9000